# What's the current state of Venus orbital infrastructure?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication, venus, navigation, development

As per [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observations_and_explorations_of_Venus#Orbiters) there have been a total of 5 orbiters successfully deployed to Venus:

- [Venera-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_15)
- [Venera-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_16)
- [Magellan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magellan_(spacecraft))
- [Venus Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Express)
- [Akatsuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft))

Of which only the Akatsuki seems to be currently operational.

Could it be used to communicate to other potential satellites or for data relay purposes to communicate with Earth (e.g. when a potential new spacecraft is on the far side of Venus)? What  would be the approximate bandwidth?

Is there any other usable infrastructure in orbit around Venus? Could it be used for navigational purposes?

Comment: It probably could do all of those things, but what's in it for JAXA? As for bandwidth (I think you mean data rates) that is much more nuanced..